Find missing rows from two data sets based on multiple criteria
I have two datasets, one of claims I have submitted to our biller, another of claims that my biller has in their system.  These data sets contain some of the same data and some different data.
I need to compare the two data sets based on 3 columns and find any rows in my data set that are missing from my billers data set.
I am open to different solutions.  It can create a 3rd data set with only the missing rows, or it can add a new column into my data set that tells me if the row is missing from the billers data.
My data:

Billers data:
In the example I need to find the missing rows based on PHN (Health Card), Bill Date (Date of Service), Fee Code (Billing Code).
Here is a link to a sample sheet that may be helpful https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gFQUQhKw2tc8ioaGHe-rmTaUWvhzq4Qq9JU7FIb4chY/edit?usp=sharing

Use COUNTIFS on the correct columns to find if it matches.  0 would mean no match.
